# Bootstrap 4 - wildly different rendered font sizes in Ubuntu Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, cross-browser

I'm developing a site on Ubuntu.  When I look at it in Firefox, it's a lot smaller than when I view it in Chrome.  Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Both browsers have their default fonts set to DejaVu Serif at 16px.  I haven't messed with Bootstrap's default font size.  It's still 1rem.

What's accounting for this discrepancy, and is there a way to further normalize the differences between browsers?

EDIT: My scss, even though it's not relevant, because it was requested:

```
$theme-colors: (
    "burnt-orange": #fa7334,
    "light-blue": #67e2f5,
    "dark-blue": #006f80,
    "beige": #f5d5bc
);

.header-icon {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

#jumbo {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#diva-sidebar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0.65em;
}

#footer a {
  color: white;
}

.errors {
  border: 1px solid #c70f36;
  color: #c70f36;
  background-color: #ffc0cb;
}

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.css";

.header-icon-link-blue {
  color: theme-color("dark-blue") !important;

  :hover {
    color: theme-color-level("dark-blue", 2) !important;
  }
}

.header-icon-link-orange {
  color: theme-color("burnt-orange") !important;

  :hover {
    color: theme-color-level("burnt-orange", 2) !important;
  }
}

.color-burnt-orange {
  color: theme-color("burnt-orange");
}
```

EDIT: After adding

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

To my custom.scss file, but the problem persists.

Comment: Please post your css so we can help you answer this question.

Comment: It's bootstrap, so...  I mean, I'm not trying to be flippant, but I'm using Bootstrap 4.1.  I haven't changed any of its base variables/settings.  The `body` element's font size is simply set at `1rem` in the Boostrap `_reboot.scss` file.  I'm not great at CSS, so I let the framework do the heavy lifting for me.  Which is why this is so odd... because I *haven't* played with the default sizing settings, I would assume things should look the same in different browsers.  So, I guess take a look at: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.3/scss/_reboot.scss

Comment: *My* CSS is only adds theme colors and includes FontAwesome's glyphs into the project, neither of which affect sizing, and are thus irrelevant to the problem

Comment: Definitely don't assume things look the same across browsers. Chrome does things its own way, and on a PC Chrome is probably the worst at rendering fonts properly. A lot of these css variances we basically have to let go of rather than fight. I would try the Bootstrap site in those browsers and see if they are the same, if so, maybe you have some other style affecting the rendering.

Comment: @NathanielFlick The Bootstrap site also shows the same sizing discrepancies, so I'm guessing it's just the way the Ubuntu version of the browsers render/display content.

Comment: I would agree with that statement. Welcome to the browser wars. :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar issue when designing sites using Bootstrap 4.x. The issue is Bootstrap uses the browser's default font size, and then sets relative font sizes from this. However, Firefox and Chrome seem to use a different default size, which causes issues most noticeably when you are using larger fonts on headings. The easiest solution is to set an exact base font size on the html to override the browser default, like so:

```
html {font-size:16px;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, making that change to my CSS made no difference to the way the browsers render my site.  The size differences remain

Comment: 2 years later this fixed an issue with a bootstrap app where the font size 16 was on the body. Moving it to html fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to prefix your css code. Because, all browsers has a prefix code so: -webkit, -o, -moz ets. Go this [Link](http://autoprefixer.github.io/) and past your css left column and copy css from right column: for example: [image] Kindly mark it as Answer if it solved your problem :)